# hibernate relationship mapping

Tags: database, hibernate, relational-database, entity-relationship

So if I have users and address tables. Because each users can buy or sell things so in the users table should have return_address, shipping_address, and billing_address. Then how can I define the relationship of these two tables?

1. Many-to-Many: because multiples users have multiple addresses (different type of address).
2. One-to-One: because each user only have one address.
3. One-to-Many: many users can share one address.

After reading some tutorials about hibernate, I find myself so confusing because now it has Many-to-One (I understand that it is a reversion of One-to-Many, but still confusing) .

Would any one mind to give me some advises and suggestions designing the database as well as optimization the database/query performance? It would be wonderful to help a new learner like me reduce the headache.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: -1: You question suggests that you are not sure how to use Hibernate overall - it is formulated broadly and the real question is not clear. 'Give me some hints' is itself a hint that working through some tutorials may be the most helpful way.

Comment: You are right. I am learning hibernate so every thing about it is so new to me. I find myself hard to understand the doc, and the tutorial usually includes simple cases which is clearly to see (the author has told it in the tutor, yah). Some advises from experienced people would guild new come learners right direction, wouldnt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User table will hold the address key.

```
@Entity
public class Customer{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "return_address_fk")
    private Address   returnAddress;

     @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "shipping_address_fk")
    private Address   shippingAddress;

     @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "billing_address_fk")
    private Address   billingAddress;
}


@Entity
public class Address{
// address properties
}
```

** Do not get confused.

**Address should be a referred entity, means it's lifecycle does not depend upon User.**

1.) Many users can have same returnAddress.

2.) Many users can have same shippingAddress.

3.) Many users can have same billingAddress.

If you say, One user can have Many returnAddress, shippingAddress, billingAddress, then add `Many To Many` annotation. Separate table will be created.

Comment: So, in Many-to-one, we usually include the id of single-side entity in many-side entity. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @IsabelIsad If my answer solves your purpose, do not forget to accept the answer